# How to set value of FormArray with the an array

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a formgroup

```
this.paramsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      mandParamsArray: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.formBuilder.group({
          inputControl: '', 
          inputValue: {}, 
          type: '', 
          class: {}, 
          label: ''
        })
      ])    
   })

get MandParamsArray() {
    return this.paramsForm.controls['mandParamsArray'] as FormArray;
  }
```

I have a dropdown in HTML which stores the layer name.

According to the layer value selected in the dropdown, corresponding mandatory parameters are fetched and stored in the array 'mandParams'

and I want to set the value of 'mandParamsArray' of the form with the array 'mandParams'.

```
mandParams = [{…}, {…}, {…}]

i.e
0 : {inputControl: 'Freetext', inputValue: 1000, type: 'Freetext', class: {…}, label: 'input_dim'}
1 : {inputControl: 'Freetext', inputValue: 32, type: 'Freetext', class: {…}, label: 'output_dim'}
2 : {inputControl: 'ListOfValues', inputValue: {…}, type: 'ListOfValues', class: {…}, label: 'mask_zero'}
length : 3
```

I tried the below options and found errors

```
this.MandParamsArray.patchValue(mandParams)

this.MandParamsArray.setValue(mandParams)

// Error: Must supply a value for form control at index: 0.
```

Would be a great help if someone would solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance